# How does dynamic space allocation actually work in this algorithm?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I have made for school purposes my own take on a dynamically allocated array using templates.

While what I'm about to ask works, I don't know how and why and I've reached the point where I need to know.

```
template <typename TElement>
DynamicArray<TElement>::ensureCapacity () {
    if (capacity >= elemNumb) {
        return; //we have space to store the values
    }
    //we need to allocate more space for the values
    TElement *auxArray = myArray;
    //create space to hold more numbers
    capacity = capacity * 2;
    myArray = new TElement[capacity];
    //copy the values
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        myArray[i] = auxArray[i];
    }
    //release the memory
    delete[] auxArray;
}
```

I need to know: `TElement *auxArray = myArray;` How does this work ? is it using pointers, are elements copied one by one ? I need to understand how it works so that I can figure out the complexity of my algorithm. I don't mind if some one tells me the complexity but the real answer I'm looking for is how does that work ?

Also `myArray = new TElement[capacity];` I do this before deleting the old `myArray` does this delete the old one ? or is it still floating somewhere in memory in one form or another ?

Comment: To clarify; you're saying that you wrote this code, but that you don't know how any of it works?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well ofc. C++ is very complex. I do not have a complete understanding of it. I can easily do stupid stuff like Creating 500 dynamically allocated arrays and without de-allocating them and flowing trough memory but me having no idea because 500 * 10 int is not that much ram (0.019 mb). I cold not notice that even if it was the difference between life and death.

Comment: It is essential to understand all that stuff, but in real code you should favour using smart pointers over raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects. Have a look at [C++11 smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
TElement *auxArray = myArray;
```

just means that `auxArray` points to whatever `myArray` is pointing to. There is no copying of anything else, it is just a pointer copy.

This

```
myArray = new TElement[capacity];
```

means that `myArray` now points to a new, dynamically allocated TElement array. The expression doesn't delete anything. But `auxArray` is pointing to what `myArray` was pointing before this assignment, so when you delete `auxArray`, you release the resources originally pointed to by `myArray`.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies just about everything. Thank you!

Comment: @Kalec good to hear that. Then maybe you can accept the answer, so that other readers don't think your question is still unanswered.